# Mass of a membrane with integral

Tags: integration

I need to calculate the mass of a membrane,

Given that:
$$D=\{ (x,y) | y \leq  1 , x^2 \leq y \} $$

And the membrane density is:
$$f(x,y)=y$$

Thank you.

Comment: Integrate $f$ over $D$.

Comment: The constaint is $x^2 \leq y$ with $y \leq 1$, so $x^2 \leq 1\Rightarrow -1 \leq x \leq 1$ . The region $D$ is the area of the graph $f(x) = x^2$ where $f(x) \leq 1$. So, the integral bounds are $$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{x^2}^{1} f(x,y) \;\text{d}y \, \text{d}x$$ (or, also valid:) $$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}} f(x,y) \;\text{d}x\, \text{d}y$$ (graph: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MuCoE.png)

Answer (score 0):

For a small region $dA = dx\,dy$, a small piece of mass is (by definition) $dm = f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$. Thus,

$$m = \int_D f(x,y)\,dA$$

Draw out the region $D$ to find the proper bounds for the integral.